# Why am I not seeing my mesh in sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting

Why am I not seeing my mesh in sculpt mode? Did I toggle something off?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to see the mesh by default in *Sculpt* mode, but to display the wireframe of all the objects, go into the *Viewport Overlays* panel and click on the *Wireframe* option:

[image]

To display the wireframe of this object only, go into the *Object panel > Viewport Display* and enable the *Wireframe* option:

[image]

Comment: Ah great thank you!